# Strange ehcache behaviour with hibernate 4 + jboss 7.1.1

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ehcache

I have configured hibernate 4 with ehcache in my webapp that runs in a Jboss 7.1.1 and something really strange is happening:

In the login page, before the user has logged in, I have an image that is stored in the database, I have cached that image with the following parameters:

```
<cache
    name="myapp.war#myPersistenceUnit.com.model.ImageEntity"
    maxElementsInMemory="100"
    eternal="true"/>
```

The entity is annotated like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Image")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ImageEntity implements Serializable
```

I have a EJB that finds the entity:

```
@Stateless
public class ImgSessionBean {
    public byte[] getImageBytes() throws IOException {
        ImageEntity img = getEntityManager().find(ImageEntity.class, IMG_ID);

        return img.getBytes();
    }
}
```

And a servlet that exposes that method to the web:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/image")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

    @EJB
    private ImgSessionBean imgBean;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        byte[] bytesImagem = imgBean.getImageBytes();

        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setContentLength(bytesImagem.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"image.png\"");

        try (BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            output.write(bytesImagem);
        }
    }
}
```

The login page has a tag that calls the method from the servlet:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/image" />
```

So, when I load the page for the first time, I can see in the logs that hibernate queries the database to get the image. The subsequent requests to that same page show me that no query runs against the database, so we can assume that EhCache is doing its job. Up to now, everything is working as expected.

When I log in, the same image is displayed in the header of every secured page, kinda like a banner or something, using the same `<h:graphicImage value="/image" />` tag. However, if I reload any secured page, I can see in the logs that hibernate is hitting the database:

```
/* load com.model.ImageEntity */ select
    img0_.id as id88_0_,
    img0_.bytes as bytes2_88_0_
from
    Image img0_ 
where
    img0_.id=?
```

I'm having a really hard time figuring out why this is happening. Could it be because I've started a user session? Or something related to transactions?

I have enabled ehcache logs, but nothing interesting shows up.

[edit]

Another evidence that proves the cache does work on my login page. I have followed this (very nice) [post](http://josephmarques.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/performance-monitoring-using-hibernate/) about Hibernate statistics, this is where the logs tell me:

- First load on login page: `connects=0, cacheHit=0, cacheMiss=1`
- Second and subsequent reloads on login page: `connects=0, cacheHit=1, cacheMiss=0` (cache is working)
- First and subsequent loads on secured pages: `connects=1, cacheHit=0, cacheMiss=1`

I've noticed that, on the secured pages, the `connects` stat is always `1`, and in the login page the value is always `0`.

This is the code I've used to generate those numbers:

```
org.hibernate.stat.Statistics stats = // get Statistics

long connects = -stats.getConnectCount();
long cacheHit = -stats.getSecondLevelCacheHitCount();
long cacheMiss = -stats.getSecondLevelCacheMissCount();

// Execute query

connects += stats.getConnectCount();
cacheHit += stats.getSecondLevelCacheHitCount();
cacheMiss += stats.getSecondLevelCacheMissCount();
```

[/edit]

[edit2]
I do not create session factories explicitly. I simply inject entity managers in my EJBs like so:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "populisDB")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

This is the cache-related properties im my `persistence.xml`:
        ENABLE_SELECTIVE
        
        ...

[/edit2]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely sure of second level cache hit, you need to enable Hibernate statistics:

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

and don't forget to enable the 2nd level cache too:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
```

Then you need to collect them, preferably [using JMX and JConsole.](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PublishingStatisticsThroughJMX)

Then you need to check the second level cache stats:

```
SecondLevelCacheStatistics cacheStats = stats.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("myapp.war#myPersistenceUnit.com.model.ImageEntity");
cacheStats.getElementCountInMemory();
cacheStats.getEntries();
cacheStats.getHitCount();
cacheStats.getMissCount();
cacheStats.getPutCount();
```

This way you can know for sure what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I've used Hibernate Statistics to conduct further analysis and updated my question with new input.

Comment: Is the session factory only created once or is it that you create multiple instances if it throughout your codebase?

Comment: Do you have the <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property> Hibernate property? Otherwise the 2nd level cache is disabled.

Comment: I have set `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` to true in my `persistence.xml`.

Comment: I have edited my question to include more info about how session factories are being created in my app

Comment: The persistent context looks fine, but I couldn't see all your Hibernate configs.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have a single Session Factory. I think JBoss is handling the creation for me. Is there a way to check that count?

Comment: <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> and hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true and hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true and hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory and hibernate.generate_statistics=true

Comment: You'll have to debug and check if EHCache loads your ehcache.xml or some other config or the default one. You need to make sure the cache id is right. I used to name it with the fully qualified class name, no war name or persistent unit.

Comment: I was using only fully qualified class name, but ehcache was telling me that it couldn't find it. Once I've changed to war name + persistent unit, the warning went away. I believe ehcache does work at some point. Hibernate statistics show me second cache and query cache hits at the login page... so weird...